# What is meant by delegates in C++?

Tags: c++, delegates, functor

What is mean by delegates in c++, does sort function in c/c++ which takes a compare function/functor as last parameter is a form of delegate?

Comment: Typo in the title: should be "meant".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"delegate" is not really a part of the C++ terminology. In C# it's something like a glorified function pointer which can store the address of an object as well to invoke member functions. You can certainly write something like this in C++ as a small library feature. Or even more generic: Combine `boost::bind<>` with `boost::function<>`.

In C++ we use the term "function object". A function object is anything (including function pointers) that is "callable" via the function call operator().

std::sort takes a "predicate" which is a special function object that doesn't modify its arguments and returns a boolean value.

Answer (score 2):

Callback functions in C++ can be (loosely) referred as a form of `delegates` ( though `delegate` term is not used for this). The callback functions use Pointers to Functions to pass them as parameters to other functions.
But delegates in C# is more advanced compared to callback functions in C++.

Comment: Callback functions is a C concept. Though it can be used in C++ it has been superseded by the concept of functors (objects that behave like functions).

Answer (score 2):

To delegate work means to share the work load with others. In real life, if you were to delegate your task, ie if you are a manager, you would be sharing your work expecting others to complete a task without you having to know how.

The concept is the same in C++ and any other languages having the capability of delegates. In C you could see this as a delegate:

`int calculate(int (*func)(int c), int a, int b)`

Because you are expected to send a pointer, to another function which will compute some work for you. I recently wrote a [blog post](http://blog.smartit.se/2009/11/30/function-pointers-in-c-and-python-and-their-possible-usage/) on function pointers in Python and C, check it out, you might find it helpfull. This might not be the "traditional" way to delegate work in C or C++, but then again, the termonoligy says i am a bit right.

Answer (score 1):

[Delegation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_%28programming%29) is mostly used as a way to pass functions to functionality embedded in a class (pimpl, aggregation, private inheritance).  They are mainly (inlined) functions of one line, calling functions of member-classes. As far as I know, it has nothing to do with C#'s delegates.

In this sense, a function-pointer as used in qsort is not a delegate, but a callback in which framework modules can be extended by user-software as in the [Hollywood principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hollywood_Principle).

Answer (score 0):

**Delegate**: An object that acts like a multi-function pointer with a subscription system. It really simplifies the use of static or 'object' member function pointers for callback notifications and event handling.

[This](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/pointers/article.php/c4135/) link explains Delegates in a lucid manner or you may also refer to the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa712866(VS.71).aspx) link.